# Getting data out of array separately in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using shipping system where will calculate shipping price.

this is what i get in my blade currently:

[image: screenshot1]

As you see I get `id` of state and then `name` of state.

here is my function:

```
public function index() {
        $data = RajaOngkir::Provinsi()->all();
        return view('welcome', compact('data'));
    }
```

and this is my blade code:

```
@foreach($data as $sss)
  @foreach($sss as $numbers)
    {{ $numbers }} <br>
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

here is `{{$data}}` dump info:

[image: screenshot2]

> what I want is to getting `id` and `name` separately so I can use it
>   in input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The foreach will loop through anyhow and pull the relevant info. You just then show it within your blade like so:

```
@foreach ($data as $info)
    ID: {{ $info->province_id }} <br />
    Name: {{ $info->province }}
@endforeach
```

**Updated:**

From my re read you want it as a form drop down select so you can calculate shipping fee's therefore you'd simply do:

```
<select name="province" id="">
    <option value="">Select</option> -> This will be the default select option
    @foreach ($data as $info)
    <option value="{{ $info->province_id }}">{{ $info->province }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: thanks dude, it's working perfectly. before i accept it, if I have such a code `$data = RajaOngkir::Kota()->all();` do you know how to get `cities` base on selected `province` ?

Comment: Without seeing code it'd be hard to answer. I'd suggest making a secondary question with the relevant information.

Comment: oh one more thing i can't ge it by `{{ $info->province_id }}` but with `{{ $info['province_id'] }}` can.

Comment: No probs. I'll keep my eye out for it and help where possible.

Comment: i've made second question:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48296541/getting-city-list-base-on-selected-province-in-laravel