# Getting City list base on Selected Province in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How can I get my city lists base on selected province?

my controller:

```
public function index() {
        $province = RajaOngkir::Provinsi()->all();
        $city = RajaOngkir::kota()->all();
        return view('welcome', compact('province', 'city'));
    }
```

my blade:

```
<div>
    <select name="province" id="">
        <option class="form-control" value="">Select Province</option>
        @foreach ($province as $info)
        <option value="{{ $info['province_id'] }}">{{ $info['province'] }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>

    <select name="city" id="">
        <option class="form-control" value="">Select City</option>
        @foreach ($city as $info)
        <option value="{{ $info['city_id'] }}">{{ $info['city_name'] }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

PS: My data coming from third-party website and there is no data in my database including `country` `province` `city` etc. As I was suggested to other question and website unfortunately those solutions will not work for me.

## UPDATE

my `controller`:

```
public function index() {
        $province = RajaOngkir::Provinsi()->all();
        $city = RajaOngkir::kota()->all();
        return view('welcome', compact('province', 'city'));
    }

    public function getCityList($province_id)
    {
        $city = RajaOngkir::kota()->all()->where("province_id",$province_id)->get();
        return response()->json($city);
    }
```

My `route`:

```
Route::get('/', 'rajaongkirController@index');
Route::get('/get-city-list/{province_id}','rajaongkirController@getCityList');
```

My `view (blade`:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                    <select name="province" id="province">
                        <option class="form-control" value="">Select Province</option>
                        @foreach ($province as $info)
                        <option value="{{ $info['province_id'] }}">{{ $info['province'] }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>

                    <select name="city" id="">
                        <option class="form-control" value="">Select City</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $('select[name="province"]').on('change', function() {
                var provinceID = $(this).val();
                    if(provinceID) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/get-city-list/'+encodeURI(provinceID),
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success:function(data) {
                        $('select[name="city"]').empty();
                        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                            $('select[name="city"]').append('<option value="'+ value +'">'+ value +'</option>');
                            });
                        }
                    });
                    }else{
                    $('select[name="city"]').empty();
                      }
                   });
                });
        </script>
```

Comment: I recommend you to prefer this link for further implementation: [link](http://www.expertphp.in/article/dependent-country-state-city-dropdown-using-jquery-ajax-in-laravel-5-example)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel dynamic dropdown country and state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45060108/laravel-dynamic-dropdown-country-and-state)

Comment: @rahulsm that will not solve my problem because i'm not using database data data coming from another website there is no list of `province` or `city` etc. in my database.

Comment: try dd($city) and show us what it prints

Comment: @Sohel0415  here you go https://ibb.co/dvWt96

Comment: @mafortis Look at my answer, its not complete solution to your problem, rather its a procedure that you can follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, change your controller index function to this-

```
public function index() {
    $province = RajaOngkir::Provinsi()->all();
    return view('welcome', compact('province'));
}
```

Second, make a `onchange()` ajax function call as **@rahulsm's** link, with a selected `$province_id`. Your called controller function can be-

```
public function getCityList($province_id)
{
    $city = RajaOngkir::kota()->where("province_id",$province_id)->get();

    return response()->json($city);
}
```

And your url route file might be-

```
Route::get('api/get-city-list/{province_id}','APIController@getCityList');
```

And in your view remove this-

```
<select name="city" id="">
    <option class="form-control" value="">Select City</option>
    @foreach ($city as $info)
    <option value="{{ $info['city_id'] }}">{{ $info['city_name'] }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

to this and filled this data with ajax request/data.

```
<select name="city" id="">
    <option class="form-control" value="">Select City</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I added this js but nothing changed, city names will not load:  https://codeshare.io/5Pm6oY

Comment: try `dd($province_id)` in your `getCityList` method, make sure you are calling, right??

Comment: that means your ajax call is failing, search and make a right ajax call, or make onchange jquery call or with javascript. You can see this link https://laravel.io/forum/03-13-2014-ajax-for-onchange-of-select-box-with-laravel-change-with-multiple-source-object-like-textbox1-textbox2

Comment: i tried that sample, didn't work! :\ can you update your answer please?

Comment: .are you there?

Comment: when i visit `http://domain.dev/get-city-list/21` to test url, i will get this error `Call to undefined method rizalafani\rajaongkirlaravel\app\Kota::where()` and when i change your code to this `$city = RajaOngkir::kota()->all()->where("province_id",$province_id)->get();` i will get this error `Call to a member function where() on array` any idea?

Comment: Hi again, I played with my javascript code and function as well, now I can see some changes in fron-end here is my current codes:  https://codeshare.io/ad6q1R and this is screenshot https://ibb.co/jkiiRm

Comment: seems your are very close, try `alert(JSON.stringify(value, null, 4));` in your js function before appending.

Comment: i get alert with this info `{
    "city_id": "106",
    "province_id": "3",
    "province": "Banten",
    "type": "Kota",
    "city_name": "Cilegon",
    "postal_code": "42417"
}`

Comment: fantastic, now change append to this `append('<option class="form-control" value="'+ value['city_id'] +'">'+ value['city_name'] +'</option>');`

Comment: i don't know but congrats, you have come a long way to make it